# Elasticsearch query to return first event for each day

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Suppose I have an Elasticsearch index containing documents representing events, each with a startTimestamp and an endTimestamp. For each day in the month of October, I want to know:

- how many events overlap with that day
- the earliest-starting event which overlaps with that day

Is there a way to achieve this that's more efficient than doing 31 separate queries (one per day in October), even in the case where there are large numbers of events per day (so that paginating through them all is impractical)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to change your schema a bit, it is pretty easy to do in a single query with a date_range type and date histogram.

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "event_range": {
        "type": "date_range"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {}}
{"event_range":{ "gte":  "2023-10-01T10:00:10Z", "lte": "2023-10-01T10:00:11Z" }}
{"index": {}}
{"event_range":{ "gte":  "2023-10-02T00:00:10Z", "lte": "2023-10-04T22:59:59Z" }}
{"index": {}}
{"event_range":{ "gte":  "2023-10-03T00:00:10Z", "lte": "2023-10-03T10:59:59Z" }}
{"index": {}}
{"event_range":{ "gte":  "2023-10-06T00:00:10Z", "lte": "2023-11-05T22:59:59Z" }}


GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "event_range": {
        "gte": "2023-10-01",
        "lt": "2023-11-01"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "event_range",
        "calendar_interval": "1d",
        "hard_bounds": {
          "min": "2023-10-01",
          "max": "2023-10-31"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "first_event": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {"event_range": {"order": "asc", "mode": "min"}}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output of the search will look something like this for each day in October:

```
{
          "key_as_string": "2023-10-03T00:00:00.000Z",  <---- This is the day
          "key": 1696291200000,
          "doc_count": 2,  <---- Number of events intersecting with this day
          "first_event": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "test",
                  "_id": "q0C744oBImXKNSrQtMis",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {   <---- The source of the earliest event
                    "event_range": {
                      "gte": "2023-10-02T00:00:10Z",
                      "lte": "2023-10-04T22:59:59Z"
                    }
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    "AamK7a9nEKmK/OthmA=="
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

It is possible to achieve something similar with filters aggregation instead of date histogram, but that would require you to manually write all 31 filters to check for intersection. The rest would be pretty much the same.